# Why make another for loop with the variable i and make the range len(new_list) - 1? Where does new_list[i] + 1 and new_list[i + 1} come from?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, nested-loops

```
def any_adjacent_vertebrates(animals, vertebrates):
    result = False
    new_list = []
    
    for i in range(len(animals)):
        for j in range(len(vertebrates)):
            if animals[i] == vertebrates[j]:
                new_list.append(i)

    for i in range(len(new_list) - 1):
        if new_list[i] + 1 == new_list[i + 1]:
            result = True 
                
    return result 

animals = ["butterfly", "fly", "whale", "parrot"]
#note: vertebrates whale and parrot are next to each other in the above animals list
vertebrates = ["hamster", "crocodile", "parrot", "whale"]

print(any_adjacent_vertebrates(animals, vertebrates)) 

animals = ["human", "fly", "hamster"]
#note: vertebrates human and hamster are *not* next to each other in the above animals list
vertebrates = ["hamster", "human", "mouse"]

print(any_adjacent_vertebrates(animals, vertebrates)) 

animals = ["human", "fly", "starfish", "octopus", "spider", "mouse", "deer"]
#note: vertebrates mouse and deer are next to each other in the above animals list
vertebrates = ["human", "deer", "whale", "mouse"]

print(any_adjacent_vertebrates(animals, vertebrates))
```

Basically, we had to find the animal in the animals list that also exists in the vertebrates list which line 1 to line 7 does. I understand that part but then we have to find the 2 animals who are both vertebrates that are next to each other in the animals list and return True if they are and False if they aren't. I don't understand why append i to new_list instead of animals[i]. Also, why make another for loop with the variable i and make the range len(new_list) - 1. Finally, where does new_list[i] + 1 and new_list[i + 1] come from. I am getting the correct output but want to understand the reasoning behind the process.

Comment: This is bad code, but new_list appears to be "list of indexes of vertibrates"

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where focusing on low-level details like list indices makes you miss the forest for the trees. It's duplicating a lot of the work already captured by higher-level functions.

The goal is to identify if there is a pair of vertebrates adjacent to each other in a list of animals. In other words, is there any pair of adjacent animals in which both animals are also vertebrates.

To do this, all we need to do is generate a list of adjacent pairs of animals:

```
pairs = itertools.pairwise(animals)
```

then check if any pair consists of two vertebrates.

```
any(x in vertebrates and y in vertebrates for x, y in pairs)
```

To speed this up, we would want to make `vertebrates` into a set.

```
from itertools import pairwise


def f1(animals, vertebrates):
    vset = set(vertebrates)
    return any(x in vset and y in vset for x, y in pairwise(animals))
```

(We could precompute whether each animal is in the set, but because we are checking each animal at most twice, it's not a significant speedup like replacing list containment with set containment was. But if we did, it might look like

```
def f2(animals, vertebrates):
    vset = set(vertebrates)
    vert_or_invert = [x in vset for x in animals]
    return any(x and y for x, y in vert_or_invert)
```

)